# Splicing redux actions into history

Tags: javascript, redux, time-travel

A Redux tree is pretty much a list of actions and a state derived from those actions.
Something like this:

```
{ type: "INIT", number: 2 }
{ type: "ADD", addend: 4 }
{ type: "MULTIPLY", factor: 2 }
{ type: "SUBTRACT", subtrahend: 3 }

store.getState() // returns { number: 9 }
```

The project I'm fiddling with needs to to allow **splicing** a new action into the middle of that log. For example, adding a "DIVIDE by four"  after MULTIPLY and before SUBTRACT. That action would need to be inserted into history and then any subsequent actions replayed.

This "calculator" example is *definitely* simplified, but hopefully you get the idea.

Is this a valid use case for Redux? Is there a library or common technique designed with this type of action flow in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Saw you ask this question on Reddit yesterday, and [I already answered it there](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/6s6otk/splicing_redux_actions_into_history/), but I'll include the answer here for completeness:

Yes, there's several existing Redux addon libraries for working with undo/redo-type capabilities.  See the [Use Cases#Undo/Redo](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/use-cases.md#undo-redo) section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links).

While I haven't used any of them myself, I suspect the one that might be most relevant for your use case is a lib that Microsoft put out called [redux-dag-history](https://github.com/Microsoft/redux-dag-history).  Unfortunately, the lib doesn't seem to be particularly well documented, but the authors did write [a blog post discussing the concepts behind the library](https://blog.atsid.com/exploring-interaction-history-d09a52a7d186).

You could also check out the internal implementation of the [Redux DevTools store enhancer](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-instrument), which does basically that kind of work but is really only intended for development use.  You could potentially reuse it, or modify it to better suit your use case.

Comment: Hahaha, I wondered if anyone from Reddit followed here on SO too. :-) I'm currently looking over that redux-dag-history library you linked; thanks! I just thought I'd throw the question up again to see if any other thoughts came up.